# How to name 2 similar triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences

**Question**: $ABD$ is a triangle right angled at $A$ and $AC \perp BD$ then show that $AB^2 = BC \times BD$.

**My attempt**: So in the beginning, I will show that $ \Delta DAB \sim \Delta DCA$ and continue my proof.

I noticed that I could also take $\Delta DAB \sim \Delta ACD$.

**Can anyone please clear my dilemma?**

PS: I am a student and while proving Pythagoras Theorem (that's in my course) by similarity of triangles I mistakenly a triangle's name the other way around (as illustrated above) and it led me to trouble and I had to open my book and see what triangle name should I take

Answer (score 1):

While proving the triangles similar in right $\Delta$ keep in mind that first write the common angle then $90^\circ$ angle and then the remaining ones.  For e.g. to write $\Delta DAB$ similar to $\Delta ACD$  observe that in both $\Delta \angle D$ is common to both $\Delta's$ and $\angle A = \angle C = 90^\circ$ and the remaining ones are $\angle B$ and $\angle A$ (respectivelty in both the triangles). So we can write $$\Delta DAB \sim \Delta DCA$$
For any triangle like if it is given that $${BA \over PQ}={BC\over RQ}={CA\over RP}$$ to write of similar triangles,  see numerator and denominator of first two fractions you will observe that they have B and Q common in numerator and denominator respectively. Similarly first and last have A and P common and last two have C and R common. So you can write $\Delta BAC \sim \Delta QPR$

Comment: **so using angles in naming would be more accurate and how can this be applied for all types of triangles?** I used the sides of a triangle for naming (keeping hypotenuse together and then matching the other sides) and that's how I ran into this confusion.